# Exploring a Black hole sci fi possible/not possible

Tags: magic, science-fiction, space-travel, black-holes

I'm currently creating a universe and in that universe is the human race which has been around for about 37000 years. I am currently trying to figure out what tech they would have access to what would be left unexplored/impossible. They have started colonizing the galaxy and have seeded many solar systems. They do have the ability to travel near light speed and bend space to travel farther(I wanted to avoid going above light speed to avoid weird time stuff so I went with bending/contracting space in some manner. They do have access to massive portable power sources related to a fictional portion of the story. I might make a separate post about this as travel speed is important to the story) so they would definitely have the ability to reach black holes.

I was thinking about hiding a process within black holes to explain why they don't understand it/haven't ever seen it in nature(this universe is not the same as ours but I do want to keep similarities), but I'm not sure if humans would have the technology to explore or probe black holes more intimately in 37000 years. After that primer this brings you to the main question:

If you could have any technology(say you could patch any holes in the theory or currently unknown physics with some magic/sci-fi stuff) would it be possible for a person to explore a black hole or at least get more information about the area beyond the horizon?

I'm just curious about what would be needed to accomplish this so I can decide whether or not they will have access to that kind of tech. I wanted it to have some basis in reality ,but I do expect to create quite a bit of fictional answers just depends on how much. Maybe I'll scrap this idea if it turns out badly.

Thanks!

Edit:(Replying to the question on their travel capabilities) I want them to be able to travel through space within a reasonable time period without having to deal with hard to understand time changes or what not revolving around extremely high speeds. My understanding of high speed space travel is shallow. I specifically wanted to avoid having to deal with time travel, but I wanted there to be a way to travel space efficiently. I read something about a travel method that could contract space in front of the vessel and expand it space behind it. I was going for something along this line. I also was thinking about some sort of wormhole but I'm just exploring options at the moment trying to get the setting right.

Comment: Just a note: crossing from inside the event horizon to outside the event horizon is exactly the same thing as time travel to the past. Once inside the event horizon, the rest of the universe is in the past.

Comment: Hi, Woli. You're asking for a lot. There's a concept called The Technological Singularity, whereby science becomes so advanced that we couldn't possibly imagine what life would be like after the event. Your question asks what their science would be like, and that can only be answered with a massive amount of speculation.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "They do have the ability to travel near light speed and bend space to travel farther(I wanted to avoid going above light speed to avoid weird time stuff so I went with bending/contracting space in some manner." It sounds like you are describing Alcubierre drives, which when used to travel faster than the speed of light, can cause time travel.

Comment: As far as event horizons are concerned, they can't actually form. All math performed on "inside an event horizon" presumes that the event horizon already exists. General relativity works the same way that special relativity works. A star attempting to form an event horizon would experience asymptotically slower time, the same as an object trying to exceed the speed of light. Black holes will evaporate before they form event horizons.

Comment: This is a reply to previous comments. Hey Robert Rapplean the whole idea of the technological Singularity does somewhat answer my question as I don't want their technology to be so unbelievably powerful. I just wasn't sure how far advanced tech would need to be to be able to access or understand this. That said the story will be largely fictional ,but I want to have some sort of consistency with their capabilities without things being so outlandish its hard to comprehend.

Comment: @Woli, Technologies beyond the singularity aren't unimaginable, they're just not predictable. This means that the development is purely a matter of speculation. This site doesn't like questions where the answer is pure speculation. I've focused on the black hole end of things in my answer.

Comment: Ah thanks for the update and clarification Robert. I didn't intend to break any website etiquette.

Comment: @woli The contracting and expanding space in front of and behind the vessel is an Alcubierre drive, which from what I understand from a google search also can create time paradoxes if used to travel faster than the speed of light.

Comment: To make a point: it's posited that humans have been around for 200k-300k years, and despite that 99.9% of our technology was invented in the last (I kid you not) 150 years. Now, I'm jumping to conclusions because the length of time you set for your human race is nowhere near long enough to develop radio, much less intragalactic space flight. So I'm assuming you mean *another* 37,000 years. What tech would they have? Clarkean magic. In other words, they can do anything you want and nobody can say you're wrong.

Comment: Hey JBH you're absolutely right. The goal of this post was to avoid inconsistencies in logic and capabilities. For example if they were able to say travel to solar systems around the galaxy with a vessel like an Alcubierre drive or artificial worm holes would it also make sense for them to have access and knowledge of black holes.  In this case those 37000 years are not only full of advancements but also set backs. So it may not be as advanced as you would expect from that amount of time. However, it's all just fiction so I can say whatever I want just like you said ,but I still wanted to know

Comment: @Woli The obvious answer is "absolutely." As soon as you bring setbacks into the story, the answer becomes, "only if required by [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609)." Guessing what humanity may or may not know 37,000 years in the future is, as you might imagine, a bit of an unreasonable question to ask.

Comment: Exactly I'll give them what I want them to have to fit the narrative. The post wasn't about guessing what humanity will have. The post is about if possible what technology would be needed to explore or probe a black hole. This is to avoid them being able to do something without me knowing to avoid a plot hole or something along that line. Anyways after realizing the reality of the situation I decided to just go full fantasy and only have a semblance of our universe's science because it's gets quite complicated and it will just look messy if I attempt it.

Comment: @Woli OK, but you might consider reading Larry Niven's short story "[Neutron Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_Star_(short_story))," which will give you an example of what one incredibly well-versed author did to skirt around the unknown (and everything you're asking is pretty much unknown to us today). Niven once remarked, "I keep meeting people who have done mathematical treatments of the problem raised in the short story 'Neutron Star' ... Alas and dammit, Shaeffer can't survive. It turns out that his ship leaves the star spinning, and keeps the spin." (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... What that comment by Niven means is that we're constantly learning, but what we're learning about is only occasionally about the celestial objects themselves. Most of our knowledge is about celestial mechanics (how things orbit). Niven didn't consider time dilation with his neutron star story because he was focusing on tidal gravity forces. That's important - you don't need to focus on *everything.* It's also important that the way he generalized ship operations was intentional - because anything you stick your neck out for can be beaten down. Only worry about what you need.

Comment: I think I get the point. If you can't explain it don't explain it and more detail isn't necessarily good for a story. I  went down a rabbit hole with this whole black hole thing. It didn't really work out but I still learned a bit and it gave me a potential plot point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not without weird time stuff**

Let's say that your civilization tries to get information out of a black hole by sending an explorer in past the event horizon who sends a message, which arrives outside the black hole, in a finite amount of time. They could use some alternative process, but from the point of view of relativity, these details are mostly irrelevant.

From the point of view of an outside observer, the explorer will never reach the event horizon. Therefore, this outside observer will receive the message before the explorer even enters the black hole. This also means that the explorer themself will be able to receive their own message from when they are inside the black hole before they are even in the black hole.

Say the civilization patches the black hole to remove the event horizon. Because this effect will travel at the speed of light or slower, you again get the same problem: the information will come out of the black hole before the patch reaches the black hole.

For small black holes (ones that are created in a lab for example), it is possible that physics (depending on what theory of quantum gravity is actually correct) might allow a civilization to measure its [hawking radiation](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-most-famous-paradox-in-physics-nears-its-end-20201029/) to get information, say about a probe that was involved in the formation of the black hole. Doing so would require the a way to form black holes in a lab, which would ultimately be a source of near infinite energy (by hawking radiation again). But exploring the interiors of existing black holes in this manner would require such an absurd amount of time as to be impossible.

Comment: Robert, I'm not necessarily interested in handwaving the information leaving the blackhole I just wanted to understand what would be needed to access a blackhole to see if the technology they have is capable of this. So I suppose it was more of a question of maintaining consistency in their capabilities rather then needing to use it to explain away something about a blackhole. Also, I edited the post as an update to the question you posted about their travel capabilities. Any comments or thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Robert!

Comment: @woli I edited the last paragraph of my answer. I hope this better addresses your question.

Answer (score 4):

The technology that your civilization would need to explore the inside of a black hole is "space folding." This would allow access to the inside of a black hole without having to pass through the zone where time is essentially frozen.

For a sphere, gravitational forces cancel out in the center. You'd still have to contend with the unimaginable pressure in the center. If you connected a wormhole gate to the center of a black hole, material would come spewing out of it on your end. That would make a fairly scary weapon.

*Update:* Woli asked how this interacts with an [Alcubierre drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive). It really doesn't. An Alcubierre drive works via relativistic foreshortening. All points in space stay in the same order, but some points are closer to each other when the foreshortening is in effect. With space folding and wormholes, you pull non-adjacent points adjacent to each other.

Comment: It's too bad [you can't get a wormhole into a black hole without forming a time machine](https://www.galacticlibrary.net/wiki/Wormholes#Dropping_a_wormhole_into_a_black_hole).

Comment: Hi Robert Rapplean, I have a question about the space folding portion of this. I updated the post with their travel capabilities. Do you think them having a vessel that could contract space in front of it and expand space behind it is similar to folding space? I wanted to get an idea of whether their capabilities are consistent with being able to fold space into a black hole if they have a vessel like this. If that's true I'll have to scrap that travel method as I don't particularly want their civilization to be able to access black holes.

Comment: @BMF, That article presumes that you have to move one end of the wormhole into the black hole. That has the exact same issue as the formation of event horizons in the first place. It can't happen in finite time. Imagine, instead, folding a piece of paper. You don't have to start the fold in the middle and work it towards the edges, you can just roll the paper and touch the edges together.

Comment: @RobertRapplean I don't really get your paper analogy. Physics is local and wormholes can't be opened to remote locations. Both wormholes are created side-by-side, and one wormhole has to be transported, in this case through an event horizon. If it's really true that event horizons can't form (the collapsing star can't in its own proper time?) then as one wormhole descends in the gravity well you end up with a situation like a wormhole in a relativistic rocket, leading to CTCs. The other wormhole will have to move far away or be time dilated in a synchrotron or something.

Comment: @BMF, I shouldn't have used the word "wormhole," because you're stuck on it now. Folding space is a different phenomena from wormholes.

Answer (score 2):

Alright since the answers so far have some common misconceptions in them, ill try my best to give an accurat but simple answer.

TLDR; No.

A Black Hole, in General Relativity, has 3 intrinsic attributes. That being, properties of the Singularity itself. Mass, Spin and Charge. Mass is simple, it is the total Energy / weight of the thing. Spin, or angular momentum, is a side effect of the Size. This is related to the conservation of Angular Momentium. I.e if something big that spins slowly becomes very small it spins faster. Hence, Black Hole singularities ALL spin. Some spin at up to 99% the Speed of Light. These are known as "Kerr Black Holes". Lastly, Charge is the most useless attribute. Basically, we know that if you throw a bunch of say Electrons into a Black Hole it HAS to become negativly charged. But we dont really know how that would effect things.

All Black Holes in the Universe have these 3 attributes since even a Black Hole made out of a literaly single Proton has them. However, for all intend real Black Holes probably are Neutral in charge since that is how Averages work. On average everything is neutral.

So, we can ignor the so called "Kerr-Newman Metric" in evaluating your question and focus on Kerr black holes.

Is there a way to get information out of the Event Horzion´s interiour ? Well yes, there is 1 way. You can jump into it and find out. However, in a broader sense it is 100% absolutly withouth question impossible to get useful information out of the Horzion. And this is because Black Holes are a bit more complex than pop culture imagines them.

A Black Hole´s Event Horizon is the boundary after which it is quiet literally impossible to get out again. This can be explained rather simply. Outside the Event Horizon your distance to the Singularity can always increase. However, the moment you cross into that Horizon your distance to the Singularity can only decrease.
This is why people say "Inside the Horizon time and space switch place". Its because the way Space is curved inside the Horizon you arriving at the center is as inevitable as tomorrow being Thursday.

The more accurat explaination is that inside the Event Horizon spacetime contracts faster than the speed of light, hence it is impossible to get out since Spacetime drags you down no matter how much you resist it.

And this fact of life dosnt change no matter how creative you get. Some people brought up Wormholes and i would like to comment that Wormholes are so theoretical that they almost certainly dont actually exsist. Similar to White Holes. Its just a funny math trick.

No matter how advanced your tech is, there is no way to get Information out of a Black Holes Horizon. Quiet literally the only way to find out what really goes on inside is to take one for the team and go in.
Now, this dosnt mean having acsess to Black Holes would be bad. If we had one we could study that would probably enable us to have some fairly good guesses as to what goes on inside. But the ambiguity would always remain.

Comment: I did see some conflicting stuff on wormholes online(the usual internet stuff one site says the exact opposite). One was saying that there are 4 types of wormholes and each has a different set duration it would take to travel through depending on throat constriction and exotic energy or somethin like that. The other said it was just a byproduct of General Relativity math and would never actually exist. I also appreciate the layman's terms this gives me a better idea on how to treat black holes in the universe I made. Thanks Blender

Comment: @Woli As someone who has worked closly with actual Physics major´s and currently spends his time visualising concepts of GR (like Kerr Black Holes) for Universities and Studios, let me tell you wormholes are not real. As in they are valid solutions to GR. Just like Multipling both sides with 0 is valid since 0 = 0 is true (Hyperbolic !!!). Wormholes, just like White Holes, mathematically work. But they are physically implausible. Similar to  how a black hole can spin faster than c, in the math. Dosnt mean it can do that irl. 

So, always be careful with these more abstract concepts.